# Can't open .sql file for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

I have an older version of Navicat I Installed on MySQL 5.1 due to a .sql file I was given that I need to export data from. When I try to use the Loader in Navicat to load the .sql file I immediately get an Out Of Memory Error. I am lost in MySQL as I never use it only MSSQL. Any thoughts on how I can get this to load? Also I literally have no knowledge of MySQL so please be easy on me.. and detailed ;-)

Also box has 32 gig of ram so memory... yeah we have that.... Also any free piece of software that you know if that can load and export a text file will work too.

Comment: Are you asking how to exexute the SQL? If so, one way is to run the MySQL command line tool and another one is to use the workbench tool.

Comment: I tried from the console but it immediately threw an out of memory error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well opened it up in Pilot Edit and saved it out as a text file. Easy enough. .sql files seems to be one giant text file with info to create the table and import that data all in one shot.

Comment: And there are many table structures in that file so I'm back to square on. Any ideas????